# Member only pages with $_SESSION and $_GET

Tags: php, if-statement

Code:

```
<?php
//initializing script, do not modify
session_start();
define('IN_SCRIPT', true); //so that global.php cannot be accessed directly
$_SCRIPTNAME = 'default.php';
include 'global.php';
$db = new MyDB(); //mysql class
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $action == "login") {
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=overview");
    exit;
} elseif($action == 'logout') {
    session_unset();
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=login");
    exit;
} else {
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=login");
    exit;
}

//display proper template for the action defined (if none found, 404)
$template = $db->selectFrom("template", null, array("name" => mysql_real_escape_string($action)));
if(!empty($template['result']['0'])) {
    $template = $template['result']['0'];
    eval("echo \"".$template['html']."\";");
} else {
    $template = $db->selectFrom("template", null, array("name" => "404"));
    $template = $template['result']['0'];
    eval("echo \"".$template['html']."\";");
}
?>
```

In the database, I have a table `templates` with a couple rows in the format `name/html` where `name` is the name of the template and `html` is the template itself. Eval is required AFAIK and nothing is user inputted in the templates so it should be safe.

A sample URL would be: `http://localhost/default.php?action=login`

My question is: why would

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $action == "login") {
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=overview");
    exit;
} elseif($action == 'logout') {
    session_unset();
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=login");
    exit;
} else {
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=login");
    exit;
}
```

not redirect to default.php?action=login if the 'user' session is not set and the action is not logout? I'm trying to make it so users not logged in cannot access the 'overview' page.

Thank you.

Comment: for a start i think this is wrong:   $action == "login") {
It shouldnt be $_GET['action']=="login" ? the $action get initialized but the first 'elseif' doesnt know it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your if/elseif block.

You need to separate your `$action` definition from the block:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $action == "login") {
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=overview");
    exit;
} elseif($action == 'logout') {
    session_unset();
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=login");
    exit;
} else {
    header("Location: {$_SCRIPTNAME}?action=login");
    exit;
}
```

The way your code is now, it will execute the `if(isset($_GET['action']))` block and then ignore the rest of the block since those are all `elseif`s.

Comment: Now, it has a redirect loop :) Let me work on it, it's one step further than I was. +10, only need a few more for 2k!

Comment: Got it working, the last `else` needed to be `elseif($action != "login") {`. Thank you, will accept as answer when the 15 minutes are up!

Comment: @dynamic Just gotta make sure the `action=overview` case is handled.